# Primes in quasi-arithmetic progressions?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, arithmetic-progression

Suppose $\alpha > 1$ is irrational.  Are there infinitely many primes of the form $\left\lfloor \alpha n \right\rfloor$?  Is the number of $p \leq X$ of this form $\sim \alpha^{-1} X (\log{X})^{-1}$?  I know this is the kind of thing the circle method was born to do, but I cannot for the life of me find a reference for this!

Comment: Please reformulate the question in such a way that you don't ask for infinitely many primes p ≤ X.

Comment: @FGD: Whoops! Done.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the uniform distribution mod1 of $\{p/\alpha\}$ is due to Vinogradov, and the asmptotic for primes in a Beatty sequence $\sim \frac{\pi(x)}{\alpha}$ is an immediate consequence. Indeed for $p$ to be equal to some $\lfloor k\alpha\rfloor$ it is equivalent to $1-\frac{1}{\alpha}<\frac{p}{\alpha}-\lfloor \frac{p}{\alpha}\rfloor<1$. So you just need the fractional part of $p/\alpha$ to be on a fixed interval of length $\alpha$ mod1.

On a related note [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/0708.1015) paper discusses the general sequence $q\lfloor \alpha n+\beta\rfloor +a$.

Comment: "...is an immediate consequence." No, it's not, because n doesn't have to be prime for $\left \lfloor \alpha n \right \rfloor$ to be prime.

Comment: Sorry for stating it like that, I added a clarification.

Answer (score 6):

Imre Ruzsa observed that since $p/\alpha$ is equidistributed modulo $1$, we have infinitely many primes $p$ for which the fractional part of $p/\alpha$ is less than $1/\alpha$. Writing $p/\alpha = n_p - {\epsilon}_p$ with $n_p$ an integer and $0 < {\epsilon}_p < 1/\alpha$, we get $p = {\alpha}n_p - {\alpha}{\epsilon}_p$ and thus ${\lfloor}{\alpha}n_p{\rfloor}$ prime for infinitely many distinct positive integers $n_p$.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure what the "local obstructions" for $\left\lfloor \alpha n \right \rfloor$ being prime would be exactly!

Comment: I didn't quite remember the details correctly, but I have fixed them now. I would have to think more about the asymptotic estimate, so I have withdrawn my remarks on that.